# Equation for calculating the Sun's position 

Tags: sun

*[SunPosition Calculator](http://www.sunposition.info/sunposition/spc/locations.php#1)* calculates the Sun's postion based on the location and time. What is the equation used for such a calculation?

Comment: I gave an outline of that calculation in [the unusual sundial question]http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24901)

Answer (score 4):

This function http://www.astro.washington.edu/docs/idl/cgi-bin/getpro/library28.html?ZENSUN is written in IDL, a programming language popular in the astronomy community. Although IDL is commercial software, the [GNU Data Language](http://gnudatalanguage.sourceforge.net/) is intended to be compatible and may help you work through the calculation if you want to port it to a different language.